# 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim' with plot_wireframe

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Given the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Initialize figure and 3D axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Cube data
X = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# Plotting cube
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
# Show plot
plt.show()
```

It seems the variables, `(X, Y, Z)`, don't work, and produce to following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[53], line 8
      6 Z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
      7 # Plotting cube
----> 8 ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
      9 # Show plot
     10 plt.show()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py11\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py:1731, in Axes3D.plot_wireframe(self, X, Y, Z, **kwargs)
   1693 """
   1694 Plot a 3D wireframe.
   1695 
   (...)
   1727     Other keyword arguments are forwarded to `.Line3DCollection`.
   1728 """
   1730 had_data = self.has_data()
-> 1731 if Z.ndim != 2:
   1732     raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
   1733 # FIXME: Support masked arrays

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

How can I plot the 3 lists on a wireframe?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with matplotlib, but it looks like the function `plot_wireframe` expects a numpy array but gets three `list`objects instead

Comment: `plot_wireframe` expects three 2-dimensional numpy arrays.  You are providing straight Python lists.   https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_wireframe.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_wireframe

Comment: @TimRoberts based on my experiments it seems to be able to handle X and Y being simple one-dimensional lists.

Comment: Yes, the documentation states all must be 2D arrays, but the code only verifies that Z is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Convert the the lists to numpy arrays, and reshape them. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q0Lz.png). `X = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]).reshape(8, 1)`, `Y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]).reshape(8, 1)`, `Z = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]).reshape(8, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `z.ndim` is not valid because `Z` is a list.  But it's part of testing that `Z` is 2-dimensional.

Making `Z` an array, and we get the 2d error message:

```
In [46]: Z=np.array(Z)
In [47]: ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 1
----> 1 ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py:1628, in Axes3D.plot_wireframe(self, X, Y, Z, **kwargs)
   1626 had_data = self.has_data()
   1627 if Z.ndim != 2:
-> 1628     raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
   1629 # FIXME: Support masked arrays
   1630 X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)

ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

From the wireframe docs:

```
Signature: ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Plot a 3D wireframe.
...
Parameters
----------
X, Y, Z : 2D arrays
    Data values.
```